# identifying the rows with maximum continuous values

Tags: sql, sas

I have two columns in a table. the second column has 1 or zero depending on a predefined condition. Can someone help me with a logic to identify the maximum continuous occurrence of 1s. For example, in the below table the maximum continuous occurrence is between rows 7 and 18. Just the logic to identify this would be enough.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results in plain text. Also, are you using proc sql or connecting to a database? If connecting to a db, which one (MySQL, SQL Server, etc...)?

Answer (score 0):

Create the intervals.

```
data intervals ;
  set have ;
  by B NOTSORTED ;
  if first.b then start=A ;
  retain start ;
  if last.b then do;
     end = A ;
     duration = end - start + 1 ;
     output;
  end;
  drop A ;
run;
```

Then find the interval with the maximum duration.  Perhaps you want the first occurrence of the maximum duration?

```
proc sort data=intervals out=want ;
  by descending duration start;
run;

data want ;
  set want (obs=1);
  where B=1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
data have;
input A B;
datalines;
1 0
2 0
3 1
4 1
5 1
6 0
7 0
8 0
9 1
10 0
11 1
12 1
13 1
14 1
15 1
16 1
17 0
18 0
19 0
20 1
21 0
;

proc sort data=have;
by A;
run;

data want;
set have;
if B=1 then count + 1;
if B = 0 then count = 0;
run;

proc sql;
select max(count) as max_value from want;
```